# Need text value from any element with css of text-transform:uppercase

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use a script found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435339/2112423) from: Niet the Dark Absol

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), l = e.length, i;
if( typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined")
    getComputedStyle = function(e) {return e.currentStyle;};
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( getComputedStyle(e[i]).textTransform == "uppercase") {
        // do stuff with e[i] here.
    }
}
```

I need to get the Text Value from each array value.  Currently if I console.log e[i] I get the entire element i.e.

```
<p style="text-transform: uppercase;">Text</p>
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to the code to simply make all of these lines of Greek text uppercase.  I need to do a replace text on all uppercase characters that use tonos, and the css is making the lowercase letter with tonos uppercase.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `e[i].textContent` to get its text.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar!  I forgot to mention I have to support IE8 on this project so I had to use innerText instead of textContent as textContent is not supported by IE8.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Note that `innerText` isn't supported by FireFox, so you need to use whichever is available.

Comment: If the element doesn't contain any other elements, you can use `innerHTML`.